# wafv2 firewall rules to restrict domain names

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, web-application-firewall

I created WAFV2 firewall rules to restrict few IP address to hit API gateways. it is working as expected.

```
# ipsets
resource "aws_wafv2_ip_set" "example-ip-sets" {
  name               = "ipsetsexample"
  description        = "Example IP set"
  scope              = "REGIONAL"
  ip_address_version = "IPV4"
  addresses          = ["137.137.43.154/32", "40.121.120.150/32"]

  tags = {
    Tag1 = "Value1"
    Tag2 = "Value2"
  }
}

resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "firewall" {
  name = "firewall"
  scope = "REGIONAL"
  default_action {
    block {}
  }
  rule {
    name     = "ip-blacklist"
    priority = 1
    action {
      allow {}
    }
    statement {
      ip_set_reference_statement {
        arn = aws_wafv2_ip_set.example-ip-sets.arn
      }
    }

    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = "BlacklistedIP"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }

  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
    metric_name                = "Allowed"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = true
  }
}

resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl_association" "this" {
  resource_arn = aws_api_gateway_stage.api_stage.arn
  web_acl_arn  = aws_wafv2_web_acl.firewall.arn
}
```

but now new scenario came in to picture like, block some domain names instead of IP's `(abcde.com, us1a.bcde.com)` to invoke the API gateways. I have searched many terraform docs but didn't find any related.
is there any docs or source to restrict domain names to hit the API gateway ?

Comment: Well, domain names map to IP addresses, don't they? :)

Comment: but IP's are not static, so we are planning for domain names

Comment: How come DNS names are not mapped to static IPs? They will be changing frequently?

Comment: Are you trying to block browser-based requests (ie via a website front end)? If that's the case, CORS controls might be an easier and cheaper alternative. If you need to use WAF, you can set a rule to check the ```origin``` header.

Comment: Hi @chamal, do you have any terraform reference documents to achieve this through WAF..i have not find any references